# Case when time is beween and on weekends

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a case when on one of my columns, but the time has to be between two times during the week and different on the weekends. So if sched_time is between 8:30:00 and 14:45:00 during the week (M-F) then 'ABC' else 'DEF'. The sched_time column looks like this 2020-03-27 09:29:00. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Client_Last_Name,
   Client_First_Name,
   Sched_Time,
   CASE WHEN Sched_time IS BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '14:45:00'
        THEN 'ABC' 
        ELSE 'DEF'
   END 
   Field_Name,
   Recoded_Response,
   Dlsequence
FROM DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA 
WHERE SERVICE_NAME = 'Medical'
AND FIELD_CATEGORY = 'Background Information'
AND Field_Name = 'Restraint?'
AND Recoded_Response = 1
And Sched_Time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 8 AND 
    Sched_Time <= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that SCHED_TIME is of type `DATE` then you can take advantage of INTERVAL arithmetic:

```
SELECT Client_Last_Name,
       Client_First_Name,
       Sched_Time,
       CASE
         WHEN Sched_time BETWEEN TRUNC(SCHED_TIME) + INTERVAL  '8' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
                             AND TRUNC(SCHED_TIME) + INTERVAL '14' HOUR + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE AND
              TO_CHAR(SCHED_TIME, 'DY') IN ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI')
         THEN 'ABC' 
         ELSE 'DEF'
       END 
       Field_Name,
       Recoded_Response,
       Dlsequence
  FROM DAILY_LOG_CUSTOM_DATA 
  WHERE SERVICE_NAME = 'Medical'
    AND FIELD_CATEGORY = 'Background Information'
    AND Field_Name = 'Restraint?'
    AND Recoded_Response = 1
    AND Sched_Time >= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 8 AND 
        Sched_Time <= TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW') - 1
```

Comment: Thats's the one! Thank you everybody for the input.

Comment: You can also write [composite interval literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B) like `interval  '8:30' hour to minute`.

Comment: Also you can specify the date language inline using `to_char(sched_time, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = English')` rather than trusting the session settings. And the thing about weekends in English is they are the only days beginning with 'S', which can greatly simplify `case` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char()`.  Assuming English language settings:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Sched_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN '08:30:00' AND '14:45:00' AND
          TO_CHAR(Sched_time, 'DY') NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
     THEN 'ABC' 
     ELSE 'DEF'
END
```

You can adjust this to include international settings, so the value is in English -- or your native language -- if that is preferable.

Comment: I am English Language settings. I tried your solution but am getting: SQL Error [908] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword. Is this from the `NOT IN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: did you mean `CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(Sched_time, 'HH24:MI:SS')...`? Of course, that's going to play hob with the `BETWEEN` but...

Comment: just fixed(removed `IS` keyword), please have a look at the edit @HopDevvil814 . Btw, I think `Sched_time` has no null values, hasn't it?

Comment: After removing the `IS`, now I get: SQL Error [1843] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month. I tried both `DY` and `HH24:MI:SS`. And you are coorect, `Sched_time` has no NULL values.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica . . . Interesting.  I didn't pay attention to that part.  It is in the question.

Comment: You can specify the date language inline using `to_char(sched_time, 'DY', 'nls_date_language = English')` rather than trusting the session settings.